# Zurb abide check form if only another input is checked

Tags: forms

Does anybody know how to make zurb abide validate form only if another input is checked? I have a form with billing and shipping inputs and don't want my customers enter their information twice, so I have a checkbox that asks if their shipping information is the same as the billing. But abide checks all inputs if they have an attribute "required". Does anybody know a way to make it disregard or remove that attribute if a checkbox is checked?

Thank you!